# SSL - Problems upgrading to TLSv1.3

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl

I'm having problems upgrading to TLS1.3.

I ran some tests on a test server with no luck. The following is what I tried.

I installed open OpenSSL 1.1.1-pre8 (beta) from source.

I installed Nginx  nginx/1.14.0 as it supports TLSv1.3

I then generated an openssl self signed certificate for testing.

Openssl Command

```
openssl req -x509 -days 10 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout self.key -out self.crt
```

The following is my nginx config

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/sslnew/self.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/sslnew/self.key;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
```

Please note the above code is inside my 443 server context.

Then a nginx -s reload

My browser keeps displaying TLS1.2. I tried with the latest versions of chrome, FireFox, Firefox Nightly and Firefox Developer Edition with no luck.

Comment: "My browser keeps displaying TLS1.2." : TLS1.3 is not yet a standard, it is still bing worked on inside IETF. Have you lookd at https://www.wikihow.com/Enable-TLS-1.3-in-Mozilla-Firefox ?  Also https://nginx.org/en/CHANGES does not list any nginx 1.14 version so where did you see that it exists and supports TLS 1.3? (it seems to have been added in 1.13). Did you try `openssl s_connect` on your website? Your question is also not very programming related...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Google, Cloudflare and various other sites are already using TLS1.3 it's faster and better then 1.2. All the browsers I listed are displaying google and cloudflare are using TLS1.3. Regarding nginx-1.14.0 have a look at the following URL it's the stable release https://nginx.org/en/download.html

Comment: Please do not lecture me on TLS 1.3, thanks. I am just telling you that it is **still** not a standard in the IETF definition of it, hence various companies wait before activating it and even if it implemented, there has been multiple draft revisions so today two implementations may not interoperate correctly even if they both say to implement TLS 1.3. Or may need specific switches to activate it, see my previous link. And again did you try `openssl s_connect` if recent enough and external scanners such as SSLabs. Did you try enabling just TLSv1.3 in `ssl_protocols`? Show the TLS handshake...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek My apologies if I came off as I was lecturing you. I'm not trying to give any lectures; I'm the one that needs to be lectured. I know it's not a standard yet, but I do want to be an early adapter as I will see benefits from upgrading. Regarding the wikihow link on how to enable TLS1.3 that's an outdated post as all the main browsers support TLS1.3 by default now. I didn't try  openssl s_connect. I'm going to do some more testing I'll keep you updated. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I ran the tests and I'm stumped as to why I'm still getting TLS1.2. If you know what the issue maybe please let me know. I think it may have to do with using rsa for creating the cert with openssl please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Have you seen: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/TLS1.3  ? Maybe something there could help. RSA certificate should not be a problem. An `openssl s_client` with appropriate options could show the TLS handshake with your server and maybe give hints on what is happening (I do not have a solution at hand, just trying to help...)

Comment: Did you go to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html to double check your client is doing TLS 1.3?